# Statistics point estimation question

Tags: point-estimation

I have the following question, I am not sure how to interpret it.

Suppose we are interested in estimating the difference in true average mean length between the two species of fish. Calculate an appropriate point estimate of
Species 1 mu - Species 2 mu. Based on your point estimate, which species of fish appears to be longer on average?

It also gives a table full of values for each species.

This sounds to me like i am supposed to get the mean of species 1, and then the mean of species 2 and see which one is longer?

Is that the right way to proceed?

Comment: The question is not clear. Sounds like it should have a self study tag.

Comment: Show the data and the exact question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes usually, though if you were really concerned you could try the more complex route of bootstrapping and measuring the difference that way. But for your purposes, yes.

Comment: Can you really give advice like this without the data?  I would want to see how the data is distributed.  It may be that the problem is to test the hypothesis that the distributions are the same or the means are equal.  It is not clear what is wanted.